# Can you have hdd boot profiles that you can switch between?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, multi-boot

So basically I have 5 Hard drives 2 of which have an OS on them on my primary Windows 10 os i want to access my 3 tertiary drives and on occasion i want to quickly boot my other os windows 8 stand alone with no other drives visable or accessable kind of like a quarantined os

I can do it manually by deactivating drives but take a long time switching between them any ideas

Motherboard is Asus ROG Rampage V Edition 10

Comment: Sounds like a BIOS dependant feature - Maybe have a look in your BIOS settings  - the web page mentions  UEFI  -  you may be able to find a way of takling to the UEFI from linux/Windows (eg http://vzimmer.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/accessing-uefi-form-operating-system.html )  I dont have a UEFI board so I have not (started to ) played with such a system

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. Use grub4dos or a different GUI tool to create your boot options. Windows had something built in but it takes some doing to get it right.
2. Your BIOS most likely has a way to boot off a different drive. It's usually activated by pressing F9 or F11, and then you can pick drive you want to boot from. If you want a nicer options, go with #1.